# Create Enrollment on Microsoft Cognitive Services "Speaker Recognition" API

Tags: python, azure, api, multipartform-data

Microsoft Azure has Speaker Identification API, im trying to train a profile on my voice. I have created an over 30 second WAV recording with correct formatting, and would like to attach it to the Request Body.

I think I might lack an understanding of the "multipart/form-data" structure? How exactly am I supposed to wrap my WAV file to accomplish this? (Using Python)

I'm not entirely sure what I should be putting in the [BinaryData] area.

API Endpoint/Documentation:
https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563309b6778daf02acc0a508/operations/5645c3271984551c84ec6797/console

Answer (score 0):

Ended having success through Postman, the website API was not meant to be used in that way to my knowledge. Postman allowed me to just attach the file into the body and then generate python code to use.